# Algorithm for finding the lexicographically smallest string of unique characters satisfying given order

Tags: string, algorithm

How to find the lexicographically smallest string and has unique characters that satisfies the order given in the form of a string filled with '>'  and '<'.For example, answer for the string '<<<<' is 'abcde'  because 'a<b<c<d<e.How to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

For string length N make a graph with N+1 nodes and N directed edges, where `p[i] < p[j]` denotes edge from i-th to j-th node.

Then perform [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20topological,before%20v%20in%20the%20ordering.) for this graph.

Make the smallest result swapping neighbor pairs that violate natural order and have no edge between them (see section `Uniqueness`)

Assign alphabet chars to nodes in sorted order

```
1<2<3>4
graph:

1 -> 2 -> 3
          ^
         /  
        4
           
1 4 2 3  //one of the possible topologic orderings

1 2 4 3  //after 2/4 swap 
| | | |  
a b c d  //assign letters

a<b<d>c
```

Comment: But I gave example. Added picture.

Comment: I get this till the topological sort. So if there are multiple orderings possible - one of them is the answer? If so, how to pinpoint the correct one?

Comment: Yes, we can get arbitrary topological ordering, then make lexicographically smallest ordering - it is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly your input string would have one character less than the expected output string, since each character describes a relationship between two consecutive characters. And it also seems you want the output to consist of lowercase Latin letters only.

I would extend that input string, so it gets an extra "<" at its end.

We can make some observations now: if we find a "<" at position *k* in the input string, then we should output the *k<sup>th</sup>* letter from the Latin alphabet.

If however we find a ">" at position *k*, we should look for the end of this series of ">", up to the next "<". There is always a "<" following, since we added an extra one at the end. Let the position of the next "<" be at position *m*.

For those *m-k* positions we now produce the *m<sup>th</sup>* letter from the Latin alphabet first, then the *(m-1)<sup>th</sup>*, ...etc, down to the *k<sup>th</sup>* letter of the alphabet.

Here is an implementation in pseudo code:

```
solve(str):
    letters := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    str.append("<")
    output := ""
    i := 0    
    while i < len(str) do
        if str[i] is "<" then
            output.append(letters[i])
        else
            start := i
            while str[i] is ">" do
                i := i + 1
            j := i
            while j >= start do
                output.append(letters[j])
                j := j - 1
        i := i + 1
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to fill an array with numbers from 0 to n-1, such that the local inegalities are respected, and such that the lowest numbers are localised at the beginning of the array as much as possible.

A simple solution consists in reading the input string in the reverse order, trying first to place n-1, then n-2 etc.

When a `<` is encountered, the current value is written in a stack. If not, the stack is read.

Output:

```
>>    -> cba
<<<<  -> abcde
<<><  -> abdce
>>>>  -> edcba
><>>  -> baedc
```

The code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

std::string smallest_s (const std::string &s_in) {
    int n = s_in.size() + 1;
    std::string s;
    s.resize(n);
    std::vector<int> ans (n);
    int index = n-1;
    std::stack<int> qu;
    qu.push (n-1);
    for (int j = n-2; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (s_in[j] == '<') {
            while (!qu.empty()) {
                ans[index--] = qu.top();
                qu.pop();
            }
        } 
        qu.push (j);
    }
    while (!qu.empty()) {
        ans[index--] = qu.top();
        qu.pop();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        s[i] = 'a' + ans[i];
    return s;
}


int main() {
    
    for (const std::string &s_in: {">>", "<<<<", "<<><", ">>>>", "><>>"}) {
        std::cout << s_in << " -> " << smallest_s(s_in) << '\n';
    }
}
```